# HttpListener.Start() AccessDenied error on Vista

Tags: .net, windows-vista, permissions

Running this code as a regular user throws HttpListenerException (access denied).  Snippet runs ok as an administator

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://myip:8080/app/");
        listener.Start();
        //.... and so on
     }
}
```

i went ahead and added the uri using netsh (netsh http show lists the uri)

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/app user=domain\user
```

still getting the same error.  Adding ACLs did work for other projects (they didn't use HttpListener though).  I tried multiple port/application name combinations, nothing works.

Any ideas what might be the cause?

Running .Net 3.5 SP1 on Vista

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I do not understand why but here it is.  It seems that the cause is that my network card is configured with 2 IPs.

if in the code i specify one of the ips (like i did in question above)

```
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://myip1:8080/app/");
```

then to avoid exception i need to register it with IP-bound weak wildcard

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://myip1:8080/app user=domain\user
```

however if i add prefix with the strong wildcard (plus sign)

```
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:8080/app/");
```

and register with the same wild card

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/app user=domain\user
```

then there is no error and i can access my app from both ip.

Comment: Note that putting `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:PORT_NUMBER/ user=.\Users` is likely to work for all cases, for any user on that system, including domain users (as all members of DOMAIN\Users typically belong to local .\Users group, but not vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

Is that URI already registered on the system?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerexception.aspx says that would be one cause.