# How Do You Add a ServiceReference When the Service Does not expose Meta Data?

Tags: .net, wcf

This is a follow up to this post on [passing messages between two programs running on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607530/how-do-you-pass-a-message-from-one-program-to-another).

I am trying to use Named Pipes but when I try and expose the Meta data I get a rights issue error saying HTTP could not register URL http://+:/8011/Local/Mex.  I do not need to expose MetaData as this is a very simple service that is only passing an integer and will only be consumed by one other program.  If I do not expose Meta Data how do I add a service reference to the consuming program?  Here is my paired down service....will this work or do I have to fight through trying to register the HTTP address with the machine and NETSH and can that be done with users running with min permissions?

```
<service name="WCFNamedPipeTestSever.Service1" >
      <endpoint name="WCFNamedPipeTestSever.Service1"
              address="net.pipe://localhost/service1"
              binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
              contract="WCFNamedPipeTestSever.IService1"            >
      </endpoint>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using mexHttpBinding rather than mexNamedPipeBinding?